# How do I go about allowing dynamically generated urls?

Tags: java, struts, url-rewriting

I'm using urlrewrite version 3.2 framework for java j2ee (org.tuckey.urlrewrite) ontop of a struts/spring/hibernate stack and I would like to allow my users to set a friendly url for their profile. (/url should redirect to their profile) - however there are other urls that we have statically defined under root. How do I write a filter such that if the url is not in my database the app should lookup in the urlrewrite filter for the url?

Answer (score 0):

That's a little bit backwards; the app wouldn't look up anything in the urlrewrite config--the app shouldn't know urlrewrite is there at all. I see a few options.

As long as you don't allow users to create a URL that's the same as something that should be handled by S2, you could use urlrewrite to just map it to an S2 URL that does the lookup, and if it's not found, hits an error/not-found/default page.

You could also create a filter that sits between urlrewrite and S2 that does the same thing as urlrewrite, but with a DB lookup in the middle.

You could just use a [wildcard mapping](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/wildcard-mappings.html) at the very end of your mappings to catch everything else and use the URL as the parameter to a lookup action; that's probably the simplest.

You *could* write an S2 interceptor, but I don't think I would for this.